# Proving an inequality for stochastic processes using stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality, stochastic-processes

> Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F},P)$ be a complete probability space, $\eta_t$ a continuous nonnegative $\mathscr{F}_t$ - adapted process, and $\mathbb{E}[\eta_\tau]\leq N$ for all finite stopping times $\tau$, where $N$ is a constant (independent of $\tau$). Then, for every $\epsilon>0,$ $$ P\Big\{\sup_{t\geq 0}\eta_t>\epsilon\Big\}\leq \frac{N}{\epsilon} \ .$$

I was going through a text on stochastic processes and the author proves the above theorem as follows:

Set $\tau = \inf \{t\geq 0:\eta_t\geq \epsilon\}$. Then
\begin{align} P\big(\sup_t\eta_t>\epsilon\big)&\leq P(\tau<\infty) \\ &=\lim_{t\to\infty}P(\tau<t)\\&\leq \liminf_{t\to\infty} P(\eta_{t\wedge\tau}\geq\epsilon)\\ &\leq \liminf_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{\epsilon} \ \mathbb{E}[\eta_{t\wedge\tau}]\leq \frac{N}{\epsilon}.
\end{align}
The lemma is proved.

I don't understand three points in this proof.

1. How does the author come up with $\lim_{t}P(\tau<t)\leq \liminf_{t} P(\eta_{t\wedge\tau}\geq\epsilon)$? Isn't $\{\tau<t\}=\{\eta_{t\wedge\tau}\geq\epsilon\}?$ So their probability should be equal.
2. In the last inequality, how do we exchange the $\liminf$ and the expectation (or do we need to)? To get to the final result, I suppose we need $$\liminf_{t} \frac{1}{\epsilon} \ \mathbb{E}[\eta_{t\wedge\tau}]=\frac{1}{\epsilon} \ \mathbb{E}[\liminf_t \eta_{t\wedge\tau}] \ \ \ \ \text{or} \ \ \ \ \liminf_{t} \frac{1}{\epsilon} \ \mathbb{E}[\eta_{t\wedge\tau}]\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} \ \mathbb{E}[\liminf_t \eta_{t\wedge\tau}].$$ The latter case contradicts with the Fatou's Lemma, but we don't really have enough assumptions to use the former as well.
3. Even we can exchange the $\liminf$ and the expectation, how can we conclude that $\mathbb{E}[\liminf_{t}\eta_{t\wedge\tau}]\leq N,$ since the assumption is that $\mathbb{E}[\eta_\tau]\leq N$ holds only for finite stopping times but the $\tau$ defined in the proof need not be finite?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: 1.  seems like $\{\tau<t\}\subset\{\eta_{t\wedge\tau}\geq\epsilon\}$ (what if $\tau = t$).

2.  $\mathbb{E}[\eta_{t\wedge\tau}]\leq N$ for all $t\geq 0$ by assumption since $t\wedge\tau$ is a finite stopping time.

Comment: @Timkinsella Ah, I see. Thanks a lot. Is there any reasons why the author used $\liminf$ instead of $\lim$?

Comment: people do that when its not immediately obvious that the actual limit exists